How can I assign a new column that is equal to the mean of the rows of another dataframe which fall in a range?
I have two Pandas dataframes. Let's call them df1 and df2. This is what df1 looks like with dummy data:
year,weight
2023,0.392
2022,0.382
2021,0.858
2020,0.135

And this is df2
start_year,end_year
2022,2023
2021,2023
2020,2023
2020,2020
2021,2022
2022,2022

The key fact is that they don't have the same shape. What I want is to create a new column in df2 which is the average of the weights in df1 that have a year between start_year and end_year. So, for example, for the first row, it would give me (0.382 + 0.392)/2=0.387. And for the whole table:
start_year,end_year,weight
2022,2023,0.387
2021,2023,0.544
2020,2023,0.44175
2020,2020,0.135
2021,2022,0.625
2022,2022,0.382

Here's a simplified version of my attempted solution to match my two dummy tables and dummy data:
df2["weight"] = df1[df1["year"].between(df2["start_year"], df2["end_year"], inclusive="both")["weight"].mean()

That results in the following error.
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

I assume it's because Pandas assumes that I'm trying to compare them row-wise (ie I'm trying to check whether row 1 of df1 is between the start and end years of row 1 of df2, row 2 to row 2, and so forth) rather than doing a sort of Cartesian product.
I do understand that this could be done quite simply with a for loop, but that would turn this from a task that takes a fraction of a second into one that likely takes multiple seconds (since df1 has about 110 rows and df2 could have up to 10s of thousands of rows in the most extreme usecases). I want this to thus be a vectorized operation.

Vectorized approach:
# get full range of years in df1
year_range = np.array(range(df1["year"].min(), df1["year"].max() + 1))
# create boolean matrix to check years in year_range that fall between start_year and end_year in df2
m = (df2["start_year"].values <= year_range[:, None]) & (
    year_range[:, None] <= df2["end_year"].values
)
# align weights from df1 with year_range
w = df1.set_index("year").reindex(year_range)["weight"].values[:, None]
# get weighted average for each row
df2["weight"] = (w * m).sum(axis=0) / m.sum(axis=0)

   start_year  end_year   weight
0        2022      2023  0.38700
1        2021      2023  0.54400
2        2020      2023  0.44175
3        2020      2020  0.13500
4        2021      2022  0.62000
5        2022      2022  0.38200


I think it's an efficient answer.

the boolean matrix is a cartesian join, right?

@sammywemmy Maybe in a way, since it pairs each year in year_range with each range in df2.

This is a range join - an inequality join where one column from the left dataframe is between columns from the right dataframe. One way to solve this is with conditional_join from pyjanitor - I am a contributor to the library. Underneath the hood, it uses binary search to improve performance, especially if the conditions are right. Binary search kicks in if the columns on the right are both monotonically increasing - that way it can skip chunks that do not match without going through a linear search:
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor 

(df2
.conditional_join(
    df1, 
    ('start_year', 'year', '<='), 
    ('end_year', 'year', '>='),
    how='inner')
.groupby(['start_year', 'end_year'],sort=False)
.weight
.mean()
)

start_year  end_year
2022        2023        0.38700
2021        2023        0.54400
2020        2023        0.44175
            2020        0.13500
2021        2022        0.62000
2022        2022        0.38200
Name: weight, dtype: float64

You can join back to the original dataframe, if you want to keep all rows. Also, note how df1 is on the right side - this way we get both right columns monotonically increasing, and therefore take advantage of binary search.
At the moment, this is wasteful, since we are materializing the dataframe before grouping. In the future I hope to be able to do aggregation, without having to materialize the entire dataframe (that should give better performance) - however it is most likely going to be implemented in numba.
Give it a go, and kindly share your results, as well as the performance.

You can use pd.merge and groupby methods
First, expand df2 to include all years between start_year and end_year
df2_expanded = df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(x['start_year'], x['end_year'] + 1)), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('year')
df2_expanded = df2[['start_year', 'end_year']].join(df2_expanded)

Merge with df1 on year
merged = pd.merge(df2_expanded, df1, on='year', how='left')

Group by the original start_year and end_year and calculate the mean weight
result = merged.groupby(['start_year', 'end_year'])['weight'].mean().reset_index()

Then merge the result back to df2
df2['weight'] = pd.merge(df2, result, on=['start_year', 'end_year'], how='left')['weight']
print(df2)


Try:
tmp = df1.set_index("year").sort_index()

df2["weight"] = df2.apply(
    lambda x: tmp.loc[x["start_year"] : x["end_year"], "weight"].mean(), axis=1
)
print(df2)

Prints:
   start_year  end_year   weight
0        2022      2023  0.38700
1        2021      2023  0.54400
2        2020      2023  0.44175
3        2020      2020  0.13500
4        2021      2022  0.62000
5        2022      2022  0.38200


Thanks so much! This works very well. It's much faster than the solutions I had managed to create since making this post. To clarify (before I accept your answer), does this being your solution mean you don't think that this is possible to do in a vectorized manner? Or in any faster way than pd.DataFrame.apply?
